# Excel change referenced cell as a function of a certain value

Tags: excel, switch-statement, circular-dependency, circular-reference

In an Excel sheet, I would like to change the referenced cells depending on a certain value,

```
B1=A1 & C1=A1-B1 if D1==1
B1=A1-C1 & C1=A1 if D1==0.
```

In principle, this can be done by redefining the cells in the following way,

```
B1=A1*D1+(A1-C1)*(1-D1) & C1=(A1-B1)*D1+A1*(1-D1),
```

but this generates a circular reference because Excel doesn't know that D1 is either 1 or 0.

Would it be possible to define a certain "switching" function for this case?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If D1==0 then by definication your B1==0 as well, so why the B1=A1-C1, where C1==A1, so that B1=A1-A1?

Comment: Yes, that's true but this is a a dummy example, in the model that I have there is a much more complicated function. My question is more about how to define the function than how to calculate the final values (which is clearly easy just by using algebra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Excel function "IF" allows you to decide what value, either calculated or not, must a given cell be assigned. Writing:

```
=IF(expression;value_if_true; value_if_false)
```

to a cell, allows you to express the logic of your assignment.

Coming to your "dummy" example, your B1 cell contents should look like:

```
=IF(D1=1;A1;A1-C1)
```

and your C1 cell contents should look like:

```
=IF(D1=1;A1-B1;A1)
```

Should you apply the same assignment style to other cells, remember to lock row or column as needed (by using "$" before the row or column identifier):

```
=IF($D1=1;$A1-$B1;$A1) 'to lock the column
=IF(D$1=1;A$1-B$1;A$1) 'to lock the row
```

I hope this may be of some help to you.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think yours is the best approach. If I understand correctly, the If statement stops when the condition is satisfied, so circular reference will never occur with your proposition.

Comment: In fact, @user2035908, the IF statement analises the result of the expression you supply to it and, once it is done, it actually fills the cell with one contents or the other (according to that result).